# Replace All Pipe Characters in a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am taking a fairly old site and making it responsive. The developer setup the "nav" like below, no list or anything. The mobile nav will be vertical and I don't want the "|" character. I want to do this without touching the nav HTML or adding a second menu to show on smaller screens.

```
<div id="mainNav">
  <a href="/home">Home</a>|
  <a href="/about">About</a>|
  <a href="/areas-of-practice">Areas of Practice</a>|
  <a href="/in-the-news">In the News</a>|
  <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

I've tried this line of jQuery, but it seems to remove the  tags as well as the "|", leaving a string of "HomeAboutAreas of PracticeIn the NewsContact". How would I only remove the "|" and leave everything else as is?

```
$('#mainNav').text(function(index,text){
  return text.replace(/[|]/g,'');
});
```

Comment: Using `.text()` strips all of the tags and returns only the text, use `.html()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.html` instead of `.text` so you keep the HTML.

There's also no need to use `[]` in the regexp when you're just replacing one character. However, you need to escape the pipe character outside a character set, since it means alternation.

```js
$("#doit").click(function() {
  $('#mainNav').html(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(/\|/g, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainNav">
  <a href="/home">Home</a>|
  <a href="/about">About</a>|
  <a href="/areas-of-practice">Areas of Practice</a>|
  <a href="/in-the-news">In the News</a>|
  <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<button id="doit">Remove pipes</button>
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! Now, @Nicholas Kyriakides posed an interesting idea below. Let's say I can touch the HTML. Do I use the JS method above or add <span> elements and hide them with CSS. I personally like the JS version because I hate adding HTML hooks like that.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use JS but I'd personally keep everything related to layouting/design/presentation in the HTML/CSS as much as possible - You will be anyway using media queries

Comment: True. As I read your comment I'm leaning the other way. Like I said, I don't like adding elements to the HTML like that but sometimes it's the best way.

Comment: Hmm, I would ditch the whole pipe character thing - and just give a `bottom-right:1px` to the `a` elements - which would then become `0px` using media-queries on mobiles

Comment: What exactly do you mean @NicholasKyriakides?

Comment: Ohhh, you said "bottom-right" above and I was confused :)

Answer (score 3):

Can do this with css alone by setting parent font-size to zero and setting the children font size to whatever your default is

```css
#mainNav { font-size:0; }
#mainNav a { font-size:14px; }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9ndLk6gu/)**</kbd>

And for a javascript solution that doesn't replace the elements ( and possibly events bound to them) you can remove the text nodes using:

```
$('#mainNav').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/9ndLk6gu/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hmm...interesting. Never thought of that method!

Comment: another approach along the lines of my first css idea is set color to match background

Answer (score 2):

Put the 'pipe' characters in a separate `<span>` elemenet which you then hide using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="/areas-of-practice">Areas of Practice <span>|</span></a>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .mainNav a span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

---

**Or** you can just give a `border-right:1px solid black` to your `a` elements which you will then revert to `0px;` using media queries - This completely ditches the | characters and uses plain CSS to achieve your intended result

```css
#mainNav a{
  padding:2px;
  border-right:1px solid black;
}



@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #mainNav a{
    border-right:0px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mainNav">
  <a href="/home">Home</a>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
  <a href="/areas-of-practice">Areas of Practice</a>
  <a href="/in-the-news">In the News</a>
  <a href="/contact">Contact</a
</div>
```

Comment: This is the method I went with. It's really so simple yet my mind was only thinking JS. But, I couldn't select this as the correct answer since I was asking for a JS solution. I voted it up though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/6mtafkek/1/

You can retrieve only the links and append them back to the div:

```
 var links = $('#mainNav a');

 $('#mainNav').html('').append(links );


 a{
     margin-right:5px;
 }
```

Comment: Interesting, but seems like an odd way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('#mainNav').html(function(index,text){
  return text.replace(/[|]/g,'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainNav">
  <a href="/home">Home</a>|
  <a href="/about">About</a>|
  <a href="/areas-of-practice">Areas of Practice</a>|
  <a href="/in-the-news">In the News</a>|
  <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```